# Angular 2 - updating ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a list of tables. When user clicks a table, this happens:

```
(click)="selectedTable=table"
```

And a new form appeaers which allows editing of the `selectedTable`.
The form contains the following input:

```
<md-input [(ngModel)]="selectedTable.name" name="name"></md-input>
```

And a button to update the changes..

```
<button (click)="updateTable(selectedTable)">Update</button>
```

and a cancel button:
Cancel

**My issue**

When I update my input, the table list (interface) is changing too, accordingly to what's in the input. But when I change my input then clicking **"Cancel"**, the interfaces shows the table list with the updated table, which updated only in the interface and not in my server side (Because I didn't click update).

How I can revert the changes made to the `selectedTable` when clicking cancel?

**Or in other words:** How I can change my table by the input and update it in the interface only after clicking update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update only when clicking update, you'll need to store any modified values separately from the unmodified version. In this case it means you'll need to bind `[(ngModel)]="newTable.name"` or something similar, then only when the update function is run will you assign `selectedTable = newTable`.

The reason this is required is because two way binding is a near real time updating mechanism. Any change made to your input is immediately reflected in your `[(ngModel)]`.

In order to work properly, you'll need to implement `NgOnInit` to assign the model the values of your `selectedTable`, and then in order to handle a new table becoming the `selectedTable` you'll need to implement `NgOnChanges` and watch the `selectedTable` variable.

Comment: I did tried that, but then the selectedTable `name` (the current value) is not shown in the input. I tried `[(ngModel)]="newTable.name" [value]="selectedTable.name"` but it's working bugged, the first click dont show any name, only the second one, Idk why.

Comment: This is where the `NgInit` and `NgOnChanges` hooks come in. In your `NgInit` you'll assign the model the selected table, and in `NgOnChanges` you'll update the model with the selected table when the reference to `selectedTable` changes. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html for more on the lifecycle hooks.